# Android - What is the best way to avoid hiding EditText under Soft Keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Activity with root LinearLayout. I set some of the components weight to "1" to fill the gap. Now the problem is, Some EditText are hide under the Soft Keypad while typing. And I can't disable my keypad because, there are no hard keypad. How can I avoid such situation? Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the correct solution for my problem.

Here is the helping page - http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html

Thanks everyone for replying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScrollView to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Normally under these situations, you can put everything that should be visible while typing, under a `ScrollView` this way, when keyboard pops up, Android automatically scrolls (and keeps scrolling as needed) all the content above keyboard, so that user never loses sight of the control where he/she has to type.

Comment: Should i put each EditText to separate ScrollView or All EditText to one ScrollView?

Comment: Simply do one thing, adjust your layout in a way that you mother layout, has a ScrollView, this ScrollView again has only one layout, and inside this layout, all your edit texts reside. Since ScrollViews can have only one child, this setting should work.

Comment: So I have to make the ScrollView to the root layout instead of LinearLayout. Is it right?

Comment: I want exact fit of the window, the scrollview make the window larger. That is not what I want. How do I fit contents to the window while using scrollview?

Comment: ScrollView is not a layout, its a view, so it has to stay inside a layout. try to remove the scrollbars. and put up some xml and screenshots here

Comment: [My Layout](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aNTcFJMxwmu_48US0rIj56ogKd2MKDT19ZOMjrTlzEg/edit?hl=en) Here is my Layout. This layout is inside a tab. When i try to write something in the last EditText, The button and tabwidget stays top of the keypad and the EditText become invisible.

Comment: I don't see any `ScrollView` in it. please put a screenshot of what's wrong. You can put the code at gist.github.com, and edit your own question to include an image.

Comment: Thanks man Wroking :) But still have problem with some activity.